# Update the current env with the requirements describe in meta.yaml

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I would like to update the current env, juste after the git pull, with a rule in the Makefile, compatible for all OS.

```
> git pull
> conda env update --meta meta.yaml # Something like that
```

How it's possible to update the current env with the requirements present in meta.yaml ?

The export approach duplicate the dependencies and versions and it's specific to a platform (Windows, Linux, etc).

```
> conda env export > export.yaml # Bad solution. Duplicate info from meta.yaml
```

It's not sure to have the same requirements in export.yaml and all describe in the meta.yaml.

I would like something like

```
> conda env update --meta meta.yaml
```

to import all requirement describe in build:, run: and test:

Comment: 1) Do you have examples of `requirement described in build:, run: and test`, how are they represented? 2) Is your question on how to produce the correct `yaml` file or how update env  automatically when you pull ?

Comment: ```
requirements:
  build:
    - git
    - nodejs
    - python==3.6.6
    - conda>=4.5.11
    - conda-build
    - conda-verify

  run:
    - python==3.6.6
    - Flask-SocketIO>=3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a script to take care of "combining" the requirements in `build`, `test`, and `run`; and produce the desired `env.yaml` for `conda`.

**meta_update.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import yaml

with open('meta.yaml', 'r') as meta_file:
    meta = yaml.load(meta_file)

env = {}
for req_type in ['build', 'run', 'test']:   # or more generally: for req_type in meta.keys():
    env.update(meta[req_type])

yaml.dump(env, 'my_env.yaml')
```

Then in your Makefile, you can call `meta_update.py`,
followed by `conda env update my_env.yaml`.